# How do I format mixed text in Jade?

Tags: pug

I've been using Jade for a while, and I seem to have a problem with using mixed text and tags in the same paragraph. For example:

```
p 
  | For more information, click
  a(href="/here") here
  | to read our documentation.
```

When rendered, this leaves out any white space between "click" and "here", so it looks like "For more information click**here** to read our documentation".

To force a space, I use an `&nbsp;` after "click", like:

```
p 
  | For more information, click&nbsp;
  a(href="/here") here
  | to read our documentation.
```

...but it feels wrong. Is there a more natural, Jade-y way to do this? Or should I just stick with my HTML non-blocking space?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
p For more information, click #[a(href="/here") here ] to read our documentation.
```

The `#[]` is code in Jade in a String or in a Tag.

Comment: That renders as:

`<p>For more information, click a(href="/here") here  to read our documentation.</p>`

I want the `a` to become a link.

Comment: The [documention](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) and [github](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/blob/master/docs/views/reference/interpolation.jade).Well look the spaces in white!!